# How to parse JSON array in ajax response (php)?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

Question might seem simple but I could not get the answer.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "../api/simplerequest/",
  data: {'varr': "data"},
  dataType: 'JSON',
  complete: function (res) {
      console.log(res);
      var r = JSON.parse(res.responseText);
      console.log(r.data[0].rock);
  }
});
```

When **res** has has following type:

```
{
  { 
    "data" : [{
      "rock" : "north",
      "status" : 1
    }]
  }
}
```

JSON.parse(res); does the job, but when it comes to the array like:

```
{
  { 
    "data" : [{
      "rock" : "north",
      "status" : 1
    },
    {
      "rock" : "south",
      "status" : 1
    },
    {
      "rock" : "east",
      "status" : 2
    }]
  }
}
```

I was trying to parse it like

```
var r = JSON.parse(res.responseText);//as previously, but exactly here comes the error
console.log(r.data[0].rock); //nothing works
```

So how to parse that kind of 'array' ?

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: If you have `dataType: 'json'` and get a proper json-string in the response... you don't need to parse it.. it's already json.

Comment: Your json is invalid. How create it?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `success: function (res) {...}` instead of `complete: function (res) { ... }`? That way, `res` will simply contain the json response.

Comment: @MohammadHamedani It is valid actually, i get the proper value when it is single like in the first example, thanks for the response

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Then how to access **rock** element for example in second row, I mean **data[1]** ? Thanks

Comment: I tested it locally and with jsonline.com, but both of them say it's invalid! actually `{{` not valid in json, so you can't access object in object without name. @Khuma

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Same question - Then how to access rock element for example in second row, I mean data[1] ? Yes, that works, if I do **res.responseText** when JSON is single(not array) response is like simple text. If I do res.data[0] the error occurs **jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined** - same for res.responseText.data[0]

Comment: You should read the comment (and answer)  from @MohammadHamedani. He explains why you can't access it.

Comment: Right, Thanks @MohammadHamedani

Answer (score 1):

You json is invalid and change `{{` to `{`:

```js
var json = { 
    "data" : [{
      "rock" : "north",
      "status" : 1
    },
    {
      "rock" : "south",
      "status" : 1
    },
    {
      "rock" : "east",
      "status" : 2
    }]
  };

console.log(json.data[0].rock);
console.log(json.data[1].rock);
console.log(json.data[2].rock);
```

You have following invalid json that has error:

```js
//invalid json
var json = {
  { 
    "data" : [{
      "rock" : "north",
      "status" : 1
    },
    {
      "rock" : "south",
      "status" : 1
    },
    {
      "rock" : "east",
      "status" : 2
    }]
  }
}

console.log(json.data[0].rock);
```